# Excel VBA to loop through Worksheets on a series of Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Master Macro Workbook thats sole purpose is to run a macro that loops through all Workbooks in a specific folder, makes a bunch of changes, and then saves them off to a different folder.

All of it is working except for some new code where I want to loop through all the different Worksheets. The code simply keeps running the code on the first Worksheet over and over again.

```
    Sub BlendBCoding()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NameOfWorkbook
    Dim cel As Variant
    Dim myrange As Range

    Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\ToProcess\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xml")
    Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets

    Call DoWork(ws)

    Next

        NameOfWorkbook = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "I:\Common\BlendBCoding\Processed\" & NameOfWorkbook & ".xlsx", FileFormat _
        :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub

Sub DoWork(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws
        Range("A1:G1").EntireColumn.Insert
        Range("A1").Value = "Scan Components"
        Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 16
        //Blah Blah lots of standard text code cut

        Set myrange = Range("H1:H100")
        myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        For Each cel In myrange
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrange, cel) > 1 Then
        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
        Next

        'Set myrange = Range("H2:H25")
        'For Each xCell In myrange
        ' xCell.Value = CDec(xCell.Value)
        ' Next xCell

    End With
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not pointing to the range in `ws`

use the `.` beforehand otherwise you're referring to the `ActiveSheet` instead.

```
With ws
        .Range("A1:G1").EntireColumn.Insert
        .Range("A1").Value = "Scan Components"
        .Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 16
        //Blah Blah lots of standard text code cut

        Set myrange = .Range("H1:H100")
        myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        For Each cel In myrange
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrange, cel) > 1 Then
        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
        Next


End With
```

Comment: Thank you perfect. I thought I had tried that but must of had other problems at the time.